# Method name gets dropped from URL without 'www.'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, dns

I have a rails 4 app running on heroku. When try to call a method `mysite.com/signup` without `www.` in the URL, the URL redirects to `www.mysite.com` and discards `'/signup'`

Only if I call the URL with `www.`explicitly does the method get called:

```
`www.mysite.com/signup`
```

How can I get the method name to stay appended to the URL without specifying `www.`?

Here are my namecheap settings:
[image: Name Cheap settings:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your @ record is a URL redirect so anything appended to the URL will be lost when the redirect occurs.

You would need to use a DNS provider than is able to support CNAME's at the apex record - Heroku does not support using IP addresses (A records) as they can and do change. Providers such as DNSimple, DNSMadeeasy and pointDNS are a few that will all you to do this rather than using a redirect.

Comment: The line for @ had to be changed to mysite.herokuapp.com.